# Seeking the most general solution of a first order nonlinear PDE in two independent variables

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

I am seeking the most general form of the solution of the following PDE: $$\left(\frac {\partial G(u,v)}{\partial u}\right)^2+\left(\frac {\partial G(u,v)}{\partial v}\right)^2= F(u)$$where $F(u)$ is  a function of $u$ only. A sufficient solution is $$G(u,v)= e ^{(\pm \alpha u+\beta)}\sin \alpha (v+\gamma)+\epsilon$$ where $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,$ and $\epsilon$ are real constants.

Furthermore, $F$, $G$, and $u$, $v$ are real-valued, with $F\ne constant$, $0\lt F \lt \infty$, $0\le u \lt \infty $, and $0\le v \le \pi$, where $u$ and $v$ are the oblate spheroidal coordinates like those found in *Field Theory Handbook, Second Edition* by Moon and Spencer. Is there a more general solution?

The above paragraph from an edit renders irrelevant a lot of the answers below even though the answers are excellent. My apologies for not stating all of the necessary information in the original question.

Comment: do u have constraints on the functions like $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Assuming that $u$, $v$, $G$ and $F>0$ are real-valued, the general local solution can be described using the classical Lagrange-Charpit method of characteristics. This is covered in most introductory PDE books. There need not be 'global' solutions, and, when they exist, they may be very rigid. For example, when $F(u)\equiv1$, the only solutions that are $C^1$ on the entire $uv$-plane are $G = u\cos\theta + v\sin\theta+ c$ where $\theta$ and $c$ are constants, but $G = (u^2+v^2)^{1/2}$ is a solution that is $C^1$ away from the origin,  and there are many solutions defined on a half-plane $u>0$.

Answer (score 8):

Robert Bryant alluded to this in a comment but it's maybe worth expanding on.
Your PDE is a type of [eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation), which shows up in geometric optics.
You didn't specify the domain or boundary conditions so I'll assume some nice compact domain $\Omega$ with $C^1$ boundary and that $G|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$.
For a particular case I'll take $F = 1$, so the PDE is

$$|\nabla G|^2 = 1$$

although you can generalize this quite a bit.
A weak solution to this problem is

$$G(\mathbf x) = \mathrm{dist}(\mathbf x, \partial\Omega) \equiv \mathrm{min}_{\mathbf y \in \partial\Omega}|\mathbf x - \mathbf y|.$$

Things get more interesting if $F$ (which we can identify with the squared index of refraction of the medium) depends on space, but in any case my point is that **the signed distance function to any nice domain can be a solution of your problem.**

Answer (score 5):

This idea is a little weird and doesn't totally solve your problem but lets see how it goes. We begin by factoring the expression as:

$$ \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} + i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right)   \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} - i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right) = F$$

So this becomes a system of equations

$$  \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} + i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right)   = u_1 \\ \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} - i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right) = u_2 \\ u_1 u_2 =F $$

If my recollection is correct we can solve each individual equation there by considering just ONE solution and then solving the kernel problem. I.E. the general solution to:

$$  \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} + i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right)   = u_1 $$

Is given by finding a test solution $q_1$ and then considering all the solutions of

$$  \left( \frac{\partial G}{\partial u} + i \frac{\partial G}{\partial v} \right)   = 0 $$

Which takes the form $G = H(u+iv)+q_1$ where $H$ is an arbitrary smooth function of your choice. (Or maybe not even smooth?)

For the other equation it would be $G = S(u-iv) + q_2$ where again $S$ is arbitrary.

So now to accept a $H,S$ pair as a solution it must be that our two $G$ expressions are equal in other words:

$$ q_1 - q_2 = S(u-iv) - H(u+iv) $$

This is where things get a little wonky. Depending on your choice of $H,q$ that might not be solvable.

Answer (score 4):

This is really not a new answer as it stems out from [the nice idea of Sidharth Ghoshal](https://mathoverflow.net/a/432668/113756). By looking carefully to his Ansatz, by putting $z=u+iv$ and $\bar{z}=u-iv$, the *linear* PDEs he obtains can be written as
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial \bar{z}} = u_1 \\
\\ 
\dfrac{\partial G}{\partial {z}} = u_2  
\end{cases}
$$
Considering the case $u_1(u,v)=u_2(u,v)=\delta(u,v)$, by the [solution of the $\bar\partial$-problem in one complex variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3125765/let-h-mathbbc-to-mathbbc-in-ck-mathbbc-with-compact-support-find/3137198#3137198) we have the particular solution
$$
\hat{G}(z,\bar{z})=\frac{1}{\pi z}+\frac{1}{\pi\bar{z}}\label{1}\tag{1}
$$
Thus, a general solution of the original nonlinear first order PDE can be constructed by using \eqref{1} and any couple of factors $(u_1, u_2)$ such that $u_1u_2 = F$ as a sum of convolutions
$$
\begin{split}
G(u,v) & =G(z,\bar{z})=\frac{1}{\pi}\left[\ \int\limits_{\Bbb C} \frac{u_1(\zeta,\bar{\zeta})}{z-\zeta}{\mathrm{d}\bar\zeta\wedge\mathrm{d}{\zeta}} +\int\limits_{\Bbb C} \frac{u_1(\zeta,\bar{\zeta})}{\bar{z}-\bar\zeta}{\mathrm{d}\bar\zeta\wedge\mathrm{d}{\zeta}}\right]\\
&= \frac{1}{\pi}\left[\ \int\limits_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{u_1(u, v)}{(u-x)+i(v-y)}{{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}} +\int\limits_{\Bbb R^2} \frac{u_1(u, v)}{(u-x)-i(v-y)}{\mathrm{d}u\mathrm{d}v}\right].
\end{split}\label{2}\tag{2}
$$
where $\zeta=x+iy$, $\bar\zeta=x-iy$.

**Notes**

- In the deduction of formula \eqref{2} we have not used the fact that $F=F(u)$ only as stated in the OP: therefore the formula covers more cases than the one required in the OP.
- Again formula \eqref{2} is written as if $u_1$ and $u_2$ were $L^1(\Bbb R^2)$: however the formula has a meaning also if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are (in some sense) generalized functions, thus the solution is valid even if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are various kind of generalized functions, provided their product is defined and is equal to the given (generalized) function $F$. For example, \eqref{2} has a a well defined meaning even for $u_1, u_2, F \in L^1_\mathrm{loc}(\Bbb R^2)$.